# github plugin for SonarQube not working

Tags: github, jenkins, sonarqube

Almost breaking my head over this for last few days but the github plugin for sonarqube (v 5.3) just does not seem to work.

I have my java app code in github, and have configured Jenkins to run mvn sonar:sonar goal on pull request.
The maven settings are:

```
clean site sonar:sonar 
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview
-Dsonar.github.oauth=<OAUTH_TOKEN> 
-Dsonar.github.repository=<ORG>/<REPO>
-Dsonar.github.pullRequest=${ghprbPullId}
-Dsonar.github.endpoint=<ENT_GITHUB_API_BASE__URI>
```

For sonar.analysis.mode, I tried 'issues' too

Now I perform foll:

1. make change to a fork (introduce a violation as per configured quality gate)
2. commit and push to fork repo
3. Create a pull request
4. run the jenkins job using above configuration

The analysis is successful, and the plugin always reports that all checks have passed and changes can be merged. I am just not able to understand why the github plugin in sonar is not able to show violation occured and checks have failed.

Now if I merge the pull request and run sonar analysis in publish mode on the master repo, it says quality gate failed and I am able to see this in SonarQube dashboard for the project with the statement that Quality gate has failed

What am I doing wrong here? My guess is the github plugin not able to compare the changes in the pull request with that in the master repo and hence not able to report the violation. How do I fix that?

**Update**:

If at the end, I merge the pull request to master repo and re-run the sonar analysis on the original pull request (the one that got merged), it does report the violation as comments in the Pull Request conversation. (But what is the point if sonar is going to report the violations after the pull request is merged???)

Comment: Are you sure you Jenkins job is correctly configured? From what you describe it looks like you are analyzing code from master (and not from the pull request "merge" commit). Before merge => master is untouched => no new issue. After merge (and before your regular analysis is triggered to update issues on SQ server) => master contains the changes => new issues

Comment: what change should be required in Jenkins job so that sonarqube performs analysis on the pull request merge commit? I looked at Travis.sh and couldn't find corresponding change required here. if you are not aware of specific Jenkins config, what command should cause sonarqube to look on the pull request merge commit?

Comment: SonarQube analyze the code present in the filesystem. It is not his responsibility to checkout the correct commit. Travis by design will checkout the P/R merge commit and run a build on it (as it also do for each branch). For Jenkins you can look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin